# Хранение чисел для поиска среди них

Tags: delphi

В какой структуре целесообразнее будет хранить большой (до 6 млн значений) список из натуральных чисел что бы можно было быстро находить попадание одного случайного натурального числа в этот список?

Пробовал хранить все как строки и использовать сортированный `TstringList` без повторений:

```
a.Sorted:=True;
a.Duplicates:=dupIgnore;
```

а в нем уже проверять попадание через `Find`:

```
a.Find(MyNumber);
```

но мне кажется это не лучший путь.

Comment: Какая версия Delphi? Если 2010 и новее - можно использовать TDictionary<integer (Double), Boolean> - поиск будет очень быстрым.

Comment: @anton-shchyrov, kami Использую Delphi XE5. По поводу словарей читал что может быть не очень хорошо в случае большого количества элементов: [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/282902/), или в моем случае (6млн) можно пренебречь? Сейчас попробую с БД и TList.

Comment: Попробуйте. Сделать цикл на добавление в словарь 6млн чисел займет 1 минуту. У TList в отличие от TDictionary скорость поиска значительно хуже. При использовании БД - не забудьте про индексацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты:

1. БД. Для 6 миллионов записей самое-то
2. Сортированный `TList<Cardinal>` или `TDictionary<Cardinal, ...>` если требуется проверять только на равенство
3. Если Delphi старая, то обычный сортированный TList с приведением чисел к Pointer

Comment: С `TDictionary` нужно быть осторожным: https://habrahabr.ru/post/282902/